# Does Mathematica 12.1 not work with UnityHub on OS X?

Tags: rendering

On OS X 10.15.7 running Mathematica 12.1.1 when I set `$UnityExecutable = "/Applications/Unity\\ \ Hub.app/Contents/MacOS/Unity\\ Hub"` I get the error message `UnityLink; Unable to find the Unity game engine` for `LaunchUnity["ExampleData/roll-a-ball"]` or `LaunchUnity[]`.

So does Mathematica 12.1.1 not work with UnityHub - as opposed to Unity?

Answer (score 1):

sorry, Unity was not installed completely at the time I tried to connect to it from Mathematica.